# Date formatting in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to change one date to `MON/YYYY` format. How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Did you research how to do it? If so, why didn't it work? (If not, why not?)

Comment: Dates are stored **without** any "format". The format is applied when _displaying_ the values.

Comment: i search i didn't get any answer for this format and i am vary new to MS SQL

Comment: What is the data type of the column or variable containing the date?

Comment: i want to save this value in varchar column, this is we are using for identify each month in year. i trying to migrate oracle to ms sql server

Comment: So it isn't a date then. It's a year and month? In that case you should store it in two columns, year and month. In any case, what format and type is the current value stored in? Is it really a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Replace, Right, and Convert you can get the results you want:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8), ' ', '/')
```

Results:

```
Jul/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

**To show Datename/Year**

```
select left(datename(dw,getdate()),3)+'/'+format(getdate(),'yyyy')
```

Result: `Thu/2016`

**To show  monthname/year**

```
select left(datename(month,getdate()),3)+'/'+format(getdate(),'yyyy')
```

Result: `Jul/2016`

`Format` works from SQL Server 2012 and `Datename` works from SQL Server 2008

Comment: Seems like OP wants `JUL/2016`, i.e. month name, not weekday.

Answer (score 0):

Using Concat Function

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        LEFT(Datename(WEEKDAY, Getdate()), 3)
        ,'/'
        ,YEAR(GETDATE())
        )
```

Comment: Probably not. The OP is asking for the month 3 letters abbreviation, not the week day.